# Trying to insert LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I used the below code to add a LinearLayout dynamically.

```
 public void sendMessage02(View view){
    view.getId();
    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message=editText.getText().toString();

    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_odd);
    TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setText(message);
    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    l.addView(text);

    LinearLayout l2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout01);
    l2.addView(l);

}
```

When I run my application, it emulator displays error saying the application stopped unfortunately.

What am i doing wrong? Is there any other way of dynamically adding layouts.

Comment: would need log from logcat to determine the error source.

Comment: @user1509702 post your logcat so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

With this example you are not trying to insert a LinearLayout. You get the a reference of your existing LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_odd);
```

and adding a TextView to it

```
 l.addView(text);
```

If you want add dinamically a LinearLayout, you have take the reference of your ViewGroup and attach a new LinearLayout to it.

You can create your LinearLayout creating a  brand new instance:

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(context);
```

or inflating from a layout resource:

```
LinearLayour l = getInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_linear_layout);
```

and then attach it to your ViewGroup

```
ViewGroup root = findViewById(R.id.my_view_group);
root.addView( l );
```